# how can i order/set check state on a checkedListBox control from a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, checkedlistbox

I have a `Dictionary<string, ValuePair>` that contains information about a previous state of my checkedlistbox control. I want to try to iterate through that Dictionary and adjust my current checkedlistbox to reflect that. The info contained in a Dictionary is a Name as string which matches an item in a list box so I can use that to call `FindStringExact()` and then the ValuePair class contains a bool value for whether that item was checked and an integer that is an index value for where that item was in a list previously.

How can I re-set my checkedlistbox from that info? I need to mention that my list box is bound to `inputData.Cameras` list of custom class objects via DataSource property. Here's my attempt at setting the check state which works, but I can't wrap my head around how to set the order since to do that I need to edit the source list that the control is bound to:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ValuePair> item in presets.JumpCameras)
{
    int index1 = lbCameras.FindStringExact(item.Key);
    if (index1 != -1)
    {
        UnifyCamera camera = lbCameras.Items[index1] as UnifyCamera;
        lbCameras.SetItemCheckState(index1, item.Value.Value1 == true ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked);
    }
}
```

my ValuePair class:

```
public struct ValuePair
{
    public bool Value1;
    public int Value2;

    public ValuePair(bool x, int y)
    {
        Value1 = x;
        Value2 = y;
    }
}
```

One can access the `inputData.Cameras` and that will return a `List<UnifyCamera>` where `UnifyCamera.Name` will match/or not if it doesn't exist in the current control a Key value from the Dictionary.

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve] for us to help, along with the types involved and whether or not this is WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went at it a little brute force method and split the task into two sequences of things. First I re-created a source list order and re-bound my list box to it to refresh. Then I set all of the check states for the items in a list. Curious if there is a more efficient way to do this:

```
// modify source list order
for (int i = 0; i < lbCameras.Items.Count; i++)
{
    UnifyCamera cam = lbCameras.Items[i] as UnifyCamera;
    if (presets.JumpCameras.ContainsKey(cam.Name))
    {
        this.inputData.Cameras.Remove(cam);
        this.inputData.Cameras.Insert(presets.JumpCameras[cam.Name].Index, cam);
    }
}

// re-set the list box bounding to re-set the order.
((ListBox)lbCameras).DataSource = null;
((ListBox)lbCameras).DataSource = this.inputData.Cameras;
((ListBox)lbCameras).DisplayMember = "Name";

// set check boxes
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ValuePair> item in presets.JumpCameras)
{
    int index1 = lbCameras.FindStringExact(item.Key);
    if (index1 != -1)
    {
        lbCameras.SetItemCheckState(index1, item.Value.Checked == true ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked);
    }
}
```